# Ethernet switch has not internet connection

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, switch

I have a shed that's been converted into an office, and there is an ethernet cord that runs from my house to the shed. Here is the current setup that is working:

cable modem (in house)
wifi router (in house)
ethernet cable from wifi router to shed

I want to add another wired device in the shed so I bought this [ethernet switch](https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/5-port-switch/tl-sf1005d/). When I connect the ethernet cable to the switch and then connect my computer via ethernet to the switch, I don't get an internet connection (all lights are blinking green for the ethernet ports however). The IP address also stays the same as when I use this device or when I connect directly to the ethernet cable (which I believe shouldn't happen).

What I can't figure out is when I connect the ethernet switch to my router using a different ethernet cable I do get an internet connection when connecting through the switch. The only difference in setups between the switch working and not working is the ethernet cable. Does it make sense that my ethernet cable to my shed has a successful internet connection but can't handle an ethernet switch (compared to a different ethernet cable which works correctly with the switch)?

Also, I have had a similar problem when trying to set up a router in the shed. When connecting an ethernet cable to that router, I still received no internet connection. I initially thought this was a problem with the router but after having the same problem with the ethernet switch I think it's caused by something else.

Answer (score 1):

**(1)** Hook up a computer in the shed to the Ethernet cable. Does this work? Does the computer have Internet?  If so, the switch is suspect  and you may wish to return and try a different switch.

**(2**) Next, try a better cable (top quality cable) and see if that works by itself and with the switch.

**(3)** Cable construction:

Use a preformed cable with ends if at all possible.

If you make your own ends (termination with RJ45 plugs) make sure you use a top grade crimper and double check your work.

Make sure the cable is not kinked or stretched when you run the cable.

**(4)** Also make sure the distance is less than 100 Meters (300 Feet).

Basically try a divide and conquer strategy to make all of this work

Comment: 1) I tried this. The computer can connect to the internet using the ethernet cable in the shed.   
2) I tried using a different (and shorter) cable and the switch worked which confuses me.   
3) The ethernet cable is less than 100 meters (I would guess it's around 40 meters).   

I'm not a networking expert, but I'm confused why #1 and #2 are both happening. Can an ethernet cable allow an internet connection but be faulty in some other aspect (thus not allowing an internet connection using a switch).

Comment: The distance is long enough that you need both a high quality cable (preformed if you can do this) and a very good quality switch.  I have done this successfully with long runs.

Comment: I amended my answer to discuss good cable construction techniques.